# Using Tkinter, is there a way to get the usable screen size without visibly zooming a window?

Tags: python, tkinter

You can get the usable screen size (screen minus task bar, regardless of where it sits) like this:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.state('zoomed')
root.update()
usable_width  = root.winfo_width()
usable_height = root.winfo_height()
```

Is there a way to do it that is not visible to the user?  In Tkinter, 'withdrawn' (hidden) and 'zoomed' are mutually exclusive states.

You can get the total screen size by adding:

```
total_width  = root.winfo_screenwidth()
total_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
```

So far I've been unable to find a way to do this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call:

```
root.attributes("-alpha", 0)
```

after creating the window. This will make it invisible, and then you can perform size calculations in the same way you already are.

Comment: Yes, that works.  I'm finding that the method I showed in the example works pretty well on Windows, but on OSX it gives some odd results.

Comment: For anyone wondering, to undo this and make the root window visible again, use `root.attributes("-alpha", 1)`.

Answer (score 4):

'zoomed' did not work for me in Linux Mint, but I finally found something that did and I think it is more portable. This can even be called while the window is withdrawn so that the user does not see the changes.

```
w, h = root.maxsize()
```

Comment: *Doesn't* seem to work properly on Windows.