# How to display a plot in fullscreen

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

i am trying to display a plot but in fullscreen. This is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
b = np.array([1,2,3,4])
plt.plot(a,b,'.')
plt.show()
```

But the problem is : this does not display with the fullscreen. Any ideas to solve this ? Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by full screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving Matplotlib graphs to image as full screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428193/saving-matplotlib-graphs-to-image-as-full-screen)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is depend on your matplotlib backend.
For Qt you may write this codeto maximize your plotting window:

```
manager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
manager.window.showMaximized()
```

And read this question: [Saving Matplotlib graphs to image as full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428193/saving-matplotlib-graphs-to-image-as-full-screen)

Answer (score 17):

The code provided in the accepted answer will maximize the figure, but won't display it in fullscreen mode.

If you are keeping a reference to the figure, this is how you can toggle fullscreen mode:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
fig.canvas.manager.full_screen_toggle() # toggle fullscreen mode
fig.show()
```

alternatively, if you're not keeping a reference:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.get_current_fig_manager().full_screen_toggle() # toggle fullscreen mode
plt.show()
```

To toggle fullscreen mode using your keyboard, simply press *f* or *Ctrl+f*.

Comment: Great answer: this instruction is independant of the window manager being used!

Comment: to save time) At least in Windows, `manager.full_screen_toggle()` makes the pop-up window "full-screen mode", which is _not_ the same as a maximized window. The latter can be achieved by different codes depending on the backend: e.g. `manager.window.showMaximized()` for QtAgg, `manager.window.state('zoomed')` for TkAgg, and `manager.frame.Maximize(True)` for wxAgg.

Answer (score 1):

If you also want to remove tool and status bar, with the `full_screen_toggle` mode you can prove:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None' # Remove tool bar (upper)
fig.canvas.window().statusBar().setVisible(False) # Remove status bar (bottom)

manager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
manager.full_screen_toggle()
```

Taken from http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Image-full-screen-td47276.html