# Figure sticks out of window after setting window to fullscreen using a TkAgg backend on Windows

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, window, fullscreen

I am trying to write a Python function that displays a grid of images in full screen mode using pyplot. When the window opens (TkAgg interactive backend on Windows 10), part of my plot is off the screen as seen here:

[image: This is supposed to be a 3 by 3 grid of images]

This is how it should look like: [image: Correct behaviour]

How can I make the figure appear correctly on the screen?

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def imageGrid(data_obj, grid=(3,3), start_idx=0):
    # set figure size to 1 inch by 1 inch
    figure = plt.figure(figsize=(1,1))
    cols, rows = grid
    idx = start_idx
    for i in range(1, cols * rows + 1):
        img = data_obj[idx]
        figure.add_subplot(rows, cols, i)
        plt.axis("off")
        plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
        idx += 1
    
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0, left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1)

    # make the window open in full screen (this line is breaking it)
    plt.get_current_fig_manager().window.state('zoomed')

    plt.show()

list_of_images = [Image.open("Screenshot 2023-08-30 170601.png") for i in range(9)]
imageGrid(list_of_images)
```

To make the window appear full screen, I followed the instructions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354515/how-to-display-a-plot-in-fullscreen) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439588/how-to-maximize-a-plt-show-window).

I have tried making the figure smaller by setting the figure to 1 by 1 inch, which is definitely smaller than my screen, but no matter what I set it seems to have no effect.

If I manually resize the window (take it in and out of full screen mode) after it opened the problem is resolved, so I was able to capture the desired look.

Comment: Why are you using `state('zoomed')` versus `full_screen_toggle()`?

Comment: I have tried both, they have the same effect. The error is also the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a [bug in matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/26733), but I have found a way to display it correctly for the first time the window opens. Note however, that once the window is resized by hand, **this will "overcorrect" and the result will not be the same**. Here are the steps:

- Run the code, so it displays the incorrect plot
- Click the sliders icon in the bottom right corner of the screen
- Set the parameters "right" and "bottom", such that the figure is on screen
- Call `plt.subplots_adjust` with the values obtained above

I ended up changing the line
`plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0, left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1)`
to `plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0, left=0, right=0.565, bottom=0.442, top=1)`, so the final code is:

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def imageGrid(data_obj, grid=(3,3), start_idx=0):
    # set figure size to 1 inch by 1 inch
    figure = plt.figure(figsize=(1,1))
    cols, rows = grid
    idx = start_idx
    for i in range(1, cols * rows + 1):
        img = data_obj[idx]
        figure.add_subplot(rows, cols, i)
        plt.axis("off")
        plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
        idx += 1
    
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0, left=0, right=0.565, bottom=0.442, top=1)

    # make the window open in full screen (this line is breaking it)
    plt.get_current_fig_manager().window.state('zoomed')

    plt.show()

list_of_images = [Image.open("Screenshot 2023-08-30 170601.png") for i in range(9)]
imageGrid(list_of_images)
```