# Matplotlib doesn't save image in fullscreen

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

[edit] As suggested by the comment in the answer, the issue is probably OS related. I am on windows 10. I have python 3.7.1 and I use Anaconda/Spyder.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428193/saving-matplotlib-graphs-to-image-as-full-screen) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439588/how-to-maximize-a-plt-show-window-using-python) topic to try to maximize the image produced by a plot before saving it. In my code, what works is that the plot from spyder figure viewer is indeed maximized. But when the file is saved into an image, the image is **not** maximized.

How can I fix it ?

My code below:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('TkAgg') # With this line on: it returns me error. Without: image don't save as it has been shown in plot from spyder.
from datetime import datetime
import constants
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
from shutil import copyfile
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
mpl.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{amsmath}']
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

plt.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 3
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 60})
plt.rc('axes', labelsize=80)
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=80) 
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=60) 
rcParams["savefig.jpeg_quality"] = 40 

dpi_value = 100
mpl.rcParams["savefig.jpeg_quality"] = dpi_value
plt.rc('axes', labelsize=60)
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=60)
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=60)

def plot_surface(zValues,xValues,yValues,title,xLabel,yLabel,titleSave,xlog=True,ylog=True,zlog=True):
    # This function plots a 2D colormap.
    # We set the grid of temperatures
    X,Y =np.meshgrid(xValues,yValues)
    zValues=np.transpose(np.asarray(zValues))
    # We need to transpose because x values= column, y values = line given doc
    # We now do the plots of kopt-1
    fig1,ax1=plt.subplots()
    if zlog==True:
        pcm1=ax1.pcolor(X,Y,zValues,
                        cmap='rainbow',
                        edgecolors='black',
                        norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=zValues.min(), vmax=zValues.max()))
    else:
        pcm1=ax1.pcolor(X,Y,zValues,
                        cmap='rainbow',
                        edgecolors='black',
                        norm=colors.Normalize(vmin=zValues.min(),vmax=zValues.max()))
    if xlog==True:
        ax1.set_xscale('log', basex=10)
    if ylog==True:
        ax1.set_yscale('log', basey=10)
        
    ax1.set_title(title)
    ax1.set_ylabel(yLabel)
    ax1.set_xlabel(xLabel)
    
    plt.colorbar(pcm1,extend='max')
    
    figManager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
    figManager.full_screen_toggle()
    # the solution here 
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

#    if(constants.save_plot_calculation_fct_parameter==True):
    dpi_value=100
    fig1.savefig(titleSave+".jpg",format='jpg',dpi=dpi_value,bbox_inches='tight')

x=np.arange(0,40)
y=np.arange(0,40)
z=np.random.rand(len(x),len(y))
plot_surface(z,x,y,"AA","BB","CC","name",zlog=False)

plt.show()
```

The rendering in figure from spyder:

[image]

And from the image saved:

[image]

[edit]

I copy-pasted the code from the answer below and the display are still different. The "figure" window from spyder:

[image]

The image saved on my computer:

[image]

[New edit]: I listed all the valid backends with the help of the answer below. They are the following:

```
valid backends:         ['agg', 'nbagg', 'pdf', 'pgf', 'ps', 'qt5agg', 'svg', 'template', 'webagg']
```

The only one that works to display a figure within spyder is qt5agg. And with this one the image doesn't save properly as explained.

Answer (score 7):

The solution is to add `plt.tight_layout()` right before `plt.show`.

Run the code below **(Note that on my mac I have to use `figManager.full_screen_toggle()` instead of `figManager.window.showMaximized()`)**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

# comment this part
plt.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 3
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 20})
#plt.rc('axes', labelsize=60)
#plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=60)
#plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=60)
#rcParams["savefig.jpeg_quality"] = 40

# I don't have the file so I commented this part
# mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
# mpl.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{amsmath}']

def plot_surface(zValues,xValues,yValues,title,xLabel,yLabel,titleSave,xlog=True,ylog=True,zlog=True):
    # This function plots a 2D colormap.
    # We set the grid of temperatures
    X,Y =np.meshgrid(xValues,yValues)
    zValues=np.transpose(np.asarray(zValues))
    # We need to transpose because x values= column, y values = line given doc
    # We now do the plots of kopt-1
    fig1,ax1=plt.subplots()
    if zlog==True:
        pcm1=ax1.pcolor(X,Y,zValues,
                        cmap='rainbow',
                        edgecolors='black',
                        norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=zValues.min(), vmax=zValues.max()))
    else:
        pcm1=ax1.pcolor(X,Y,zValues,
                        cmap='rainbow',
                        edgecolors='black',
                        norm=colors.Normalize(vmin=zValues.min(),vmax=zValues.max()))
    if xlog==True:
        ax1.set_xscale('log', basex=10)
    if ylog==True:
        ax1.set_yscale('log', basey=10)
        
    ax1.set_title(title)
    ax1.set_ylabel(yLabel)
    ax1.set_xlabel(xLabel)
    
    plt.colorbar(pcm1,extend='max')
    
    figManager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
    figManager.full_screen_toggle()
    # the solution here 
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

#    if(constants.save_plot_calculation_fct_parameter==True):
    dpi_value=100
    fig1.savefig(titleSave+".jpg",format='jpg',dpi=dpi_value,bbox_inches='tight')

x=np.arange(0,40)
y=np.arange(0,40)
z=np.random.rand(len(x),len(y))
plot_surface(z,x,y,"AA","BB","CC","name",zlog=False)

plt.show()
```

The saved image will be the same as the figure that pops up.

---

**UPDATE**

It seems the difference between the font sizes is caused by the `matplotlib backend` you are using. Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4930867/8366805), **maybe try another backend will resolve the issue**. For example, on my mac, if I use `TkAgg` backend by

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('TkAgg')
```

the figure in the popup screen is different from the one that is saved. In order to know which are available `matplotlib backend`s  on your machine, you can use

```
from matplotlib.rcsetup import all_backends
```

`all_backends` is a list of all the available `backend`s you can try.

---

**UPDATE 2**

Based on [this wonderful post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13731150/8366805), supported backends are different from valid backends. In order to find all the valid backends that can be used, I modified the script in that post,

```
import matplotlib.backends
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os.path


def is_backend_module(fname):
    """Identifies if a filename is a matplotlib backend module"""
    return fname.startswith('backend_') and fname.endswith('.py')

def backend_fname_formatter(fname): 
    """Removes the extension of the given filename, then takes away the leading 'backend_'."""
    return os.path.splitext(fname)[0][8:]

# get the directory where the backends live
backends_dir = os.path.dirname(matplotlib.backends.__file__)
# filter all files in that directory to identify all files which provide a backend
backend_fnames = filter(is_backend_module, os.listdir(backends_dir))
backends = [backend_fname_formatter(fname) for fname in backend_fnames]

print("supported backends: \t" + str(backends),'\n')

# validate backends
backends_valid = []
for b in backends:
    try:
        plt.switch_backend(b)
        backends_valid += [b]
    except Exception as e:
        print('backend %s\n%s\n' % (b,e))
        continue
print("valid backends: \t" + str(backends_valid),'\n')
```

Running this script, **the backends in the printed out `valid backends` are those that can be applied.** For those supported yet not valid backends, the reasons why they are not valid will also be printed out. For example, on my Mac, although `wxcairo` is a supported backend, it is not valid because `No module named 'wx'`.

After you find all the valid backends by running the script on your PC, you can try them one by one, maybe one of the them will produce the desired output figure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However even if the image saved is "more clean" it is still not the same as the one that shows up in the figure popup. I would like to have the exact same rendering for both.

Comment: @StarBucK You're welcome, you need `fig.tight_layout()` then, check out my updated post.

Comment: Thanks. I copy pasted your code without modifying anything and the rendering are still different, look at my edited message (and it is now more "ugly" on the image saved than what I got with your first edit).

Comment: @StarBucK I don't know why there is such difference, especially the font sizes of `AA`, `BB` and `CC` are different. I ran the script in mac terminal, and the two figures are the same.

Comment: Maybe that is an issue related to some kind of rendering associated to OS then. I am on windows 10.

Comment: @StarBucK I found a similar issue on github, check out my updated post.

Comment: Hello. Thank you. I tried your update but it doesn't work :( Still a difference. I tried some of the other answer on github but not really successfull for now on.

Comment: @StarBucK You're welcome, I think the problem is caused by the `matplotlib backend` you are using, check out my updated post.

Comment: @StarBucK Hi StarBucK, does try another `backend` resolve the issue?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't have the computer in which the script is now, I well check as soon as I have it back.

Comment: Hello again. I have an error when trying to put your code. Look at my last edit ! Thanks for the help.

Comment: I read a little too fast your answer you suggested me to NOT use this package TkAgg. But anyway I cannot switch package, if I try any other package the same error is returned to me (my "current" package seems to be qt5).

Comment: Maybe I should post it as a separate question "how to switch package" then given the answer I can try your suggestion

Comment: @StarBucK You're welcome. No, I'm not suggesting you use `TkAgg` backend, I mean if I use `TkAgg` on my mac, the two figures will also be different. Therefore, using a proper backend may resolve the issue. Check out my updated post, I provided a way to find out all the available backends you can use.

Comment: Hello. Look at my last edit, it can return me an error when trying to switch backend while it tells me I should have the backend.

Comment: @StarBucK Hello, after a little searching, I found out that supported backends may not actually be valid. Check out my updated post.

Comment: Edited again. Still an issue :((

Comment: @StarBucK sorry friend, I have no idea then ... So, you ran the script in spyder console, and got the valid backends (a list printed out at the end). Then, none but `qt5agg` is **TRUELY VALID**, while it is still not working?

Comment: Thank you for your time anyway you tried hard on this, it was super nice. If by truely valid you mean the one that can in practice show a figure on spyder, yes I agree. Only qt5agg can do this in this case.

Comment: @StarBucK You're welcome :) Just a workaround, you can also run the script for plotting in a Windows terminal (I'm not familiar with Windows, just something like a Mac terminal), maybe there will be more valid backends than spyder.

Comment: I up this now but I think the answer is probably in this topic ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47633546/relationship-between-dpi-and-figure-size