# Matplotlib; open plots minimized?

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, plot

So I've got a code that is going to make a couple plots, for which I want/have the window maximized in size. However, I'd ideally also want these windows to be minimized when they get created (mostly because it would make testing things a lot easier!) Is there any way to achieve this? I'm currently using Python 2.7 on Linux, with matplotlib version 1.3.1 using backend TkAgg.

If any other information is needed, just ask, and thanks in advance (even if it turns out it's not possible!).

Comment: This is for maximizing, but I'm sure you can figure it out from there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439588/how-to-maximize-a-plt-show-window-using-python

Answer (score 1):

Try this after relevant plots:

```
mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.window.showMaximized()
mng.window.showMinimized()
```

Comment: This seems to need the wg backend, which I don't have :/