# Maximize figures before saving

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

The question about how to do maximize a window before saving has been asked several times and has several questions (still no one is portable, though), [How to maximize a plt.show() window using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439588/how-to-maximize-a-plt-show-window-using-python)
and [How do you change the size of figures drawn with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib)

I created a small function to maximize a figure window before saving the plots. It works with QT5Agg backend.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def maximize_figure_window(figures=None, tight=True):
    """
    Maximize all the open figure windows or the ones indicated in figures

    Parameters
    ----------

    figures: (list) figure numbers
    tight  : (bool) if True, applies the tight_layout option

    :return:
    """
    if figures is None:
        figures = plt.get_fignums()
    for fig in figures:
        plt.figure(fig)
        manager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
        manager.window.showMaximized()
        if tight is True:
            plt.tight_layout()
```

Problems:

1. I have to wait for the windows to be actually maximized before using the plt.savefig() command, otherwise it is saved with as not maximized. This is a problem if I simply want to use the above function in a script

(minor problems:)
 2. I have to use the above function twice in order to get the tight_layout option working, i.e. the first time tight=True has no effect.

3. The solution is not portable. Of course I can add all the possible backend I might use, but that's kind of ugly.

Questions:

1. how to make the script wait for the windows to be maximized? I don't want to use time.sleep(tot_seconds) because tot_seconds would be kind of arbitrary and makes the function even less portable
2. how to solve problem 2 ? I guess it is related to problem 1.
3. is there a portable solution to "maximize all the open windows" problem?

-- Edit --

For problem 3. @DavidG suggestion sounds good. I use tkinter to automatically get width and height, convert them to inches, and use them in fig.set_size_inches or directly during the figure creation via fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width, height)).

So a more portable solution is, for example.
    import tkinter as tk
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
def maximize_figure(figure=None):
    root = tk.Tk()
    width = root.winfo_screenmmwidth() / 25.4
    height = root.winfo_screenmmheight() / 25.4
    if figure is not None:
        plt.figure(figure).set_size_inches(width, height)
    return width, height
```

where I allow the figure to be None so that I can use the function to just retrieve width and height and use them later.

**Problem 1 is still there, though.**
I use maximize_figure() in a plot function that I created (let's say my_plot_func()) but still the saved figure doesn't have the right dimensions when saved on file. 
I also tried with time.sleep(5) in my_plot_func() right after the figure creation. Not working.

It works only if a manually run in the console maximize_figure() and **then** run my_plot_func(figure=maximized_figure) with the figure already maximized. Which means that dimension calculation and saving parameters are correct. 
It does not work if I run in the console maximize_figure() and my_plot_func(figure=maximized_figure) altogether, i.e. with one call the the console! I really don't get why.

I also tried with a non-interactive backend like 'Agg', so that the figure doesn't get actually created on screen. Not working (wrong dimensions) no matter if I call the functions altogether or one after the other.

**To summarize and clarify (problem 1):**
by running these two pieces of code in console, figure gets saved correctly.

```
plt.close('all')
plt.switch_backend('Qt5Agg')
fig = plt.figure()
w, h = maximize_figure(fig.number)
```

followed by:
`my_plot_func(out_file='filename.eps', figure=fig.number)`

by running them together (like it would be in a script) figure **is not** saved correctly.

```
 plt.close('all')
 plt.switch_backend('Qt5Agg')
 fig = plt.figure()
 w, h = maximize_figure(fig.number)
 my_plot_func(out_file='filename.eps', figure=fig.number)
```

Using

```
plt.switch_backend('Agg')
```

instead of

```
plt.switch_backend('Qt5Agg')
```

it does not work in both cases.

Comment: For 2) I cannot reproduce. The tight layout is applied if only called once for me. For 3) I suppose a work around could possibly be to set the figure size yourself using something like `fig.set_size_inches(x_val,y_val)`?

Comment: for 2): strange. Maybe it depends on the fact that I have a lot of data points in my plot so that it take some time to expand the figure to fullscreen? 
For 3): yes if I can automatically infer x_val, y_val