# matplotlib 2.2.2 maximize plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib 2.2.2

Maximizing plot window not working after migrating to MPL 2.2.2.

I cannot figure out how to overcome this

on previous releases my code worked fine

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import numpy as np


if __name__ == '__main__':

    x=np.linspace(0,1,100)
    y=x**2
    F1=figure()
    ax1=subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ax1.plot(x,y)
    F1.canvas.manager.window.showMaximized()
    show()
```

I am getting the blow code and window is not maximized:

> "Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydev_run_in_console.py", line 52, in run_file

```
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
```

> File "max_fig.py", line 12, in 
>       F1.canvas.manager.window.showMaximized()
>
> File "C:\IntelPython2\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1903, in **getattr**
>       return getattr(self.tk, attr)
>
> AttributeError: showMaximized"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your previous installation you used PyQt where `showMaximized()` is available.
In your new installation you are using Tkinter, which does not have a `showMaximized()`.

Two options:

1. Install PyQt for your new installation and use it e.g. via

   ```
   import matplotlib
   matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")
   ```
2. Keep working with Tkinter, but change your code to tk, i.e.

   ```
   F1.canvas.manager.frame.Maximize(True)
   ```

   or any other option listed in 
   [How to maximize a plt.show() window using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439588/how-to-maximize-a-plt-show-window-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the accepted answer, in case you are not using a Qt5 frontend, you can maximize by using:

```
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches( (666,666))
```