# Uniform matplotlib figure size regardless of monitor size/resolution

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to make a matplotlib figure to show uniformly on different screen sizes and resolutions?
For example, I want my figure to be displayed full screen on a 12.3" 2736x1824 monitor and a 24" 1080p monitor. This is done easily in Matlab using normalized coordinates:

```
figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1])
```

Is these something similar in matplotlib?

Comment: You mean `mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager();
                  mng.frame.Maximize(True)` ?

Comment: Matplotlib does not have an internal concept of normalized screen units. But you can [maximize the figure window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439588/how-to-maximize-a-plt-show-window-using-python), which is then backend dependent.