# Save matplotlib chart in fullsize

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use

```
plt.savefig(os.path.basename(__file__)+".png", dpi=300)
```

to save my chart in matplolib.
This is a result:

[image]

But I need it in full size. You can see difference in title. It is inside borders of chart. I need to save it in mode we know as "Maximized window"
Is there an option to do this using plt.savefig?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure this is a duplicate. I need to save it in mode we know as "Maximized window"

Comment: Another relevant question is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439588/how-to-maximize-a-plt-show-window-using-python). Check all the answers, one of them is using `savefig`

Comment: You can just go full screen and then click the little save icon at the bottom left. That's what I've done in the past

Comment: Reedinationer, It is not suits for me because I need high resolution. I set dpi option for this.

Comment: @DeepSpace FYI to ping another user in a comment, you need to `@` them like I did to you here. What has worked for me is to specify the figure size (i.e. `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5.8), constrained_layout=True)`) and then save as usual `plt.savefig("RiskPlot.png", bbox_inches="tight", dpi=1000)`. This is another possible solution.