# Why is my matplotlib script terribly slow on macbook desktop but works fine on external monitor? (Python, matplotlib, OSX)

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, multiple-monitors

I am using a post processing plot script written in python, using python 3.7 and OSX 10.14

The script is probably not optimized, but it works good enough when I use my external monitors.
When I try to run it on my macbook pro 15" monitor (2018), it freezes and becomes extremely slow and unresponsive unless I set the figure dimension small enough.

I have no idea of the reason, and I haven't found any explanation browsing the internet. Any clue on what can cause this behaviour and how I can fix it?

This is the 'cut' version of the script I'm running.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle, Circle
import sys


def main(iter0,iterN,its,out_dir='output'):
    it0 = int(iter0)
    itN = int(iterN)
    itstep = int(its)
    a = list(range(it0,itN+1,itstep))
    loaded_steps=len(a)
    e = np.loadtxt(out_dir+'/energy_data_dynamics')
    #... load many other files

    plt.ion()
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20),facecolor="white")  #THESE DIMENSIONS WORK FOR ANY EXTERNAL SCREEN 
#    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10),facecolor="white") #THESE DIMENSIONS WORK FOR MACBOOK SCREEN

    it = 0
    for index in range(0,loaded_steps):
        plt.cla()
        plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
        #... plot many other subplots
        ax414=plt.subplot(414)
        ax414.plot(e[it0+it,0], e[it0+it,2], marker="o", color="crimson", ms=15)
        ax414.plot(e[it0:itN+1,0], e[it0:itN+1,2],'-r')
        ax414.set_title("Energy")

        plt.show()
        plt.pause(0.0000000001)
        
        it+=itstep
        if index == loaded_steps-1:
            input("Plot finished - Press [enter] to continue.")




if __name__ == '__main__':
    matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
    its = 1
    out_dir = 'output'
    if len(sys.argv)>=4:
        its = sys.argv[3]
    if len(sys.argv)>=5:
        out_dir = sys.argv[4]
    main(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2],its,out_dir)
```

Comment: tkAgg seems to have significant issues on MacOS - perhaps try using pyqt5 or the macOSx backend.  You may also reconsider using a figure size that is so gigantic.  20 inches x 20 inches is bigger than most monitors, unless you have a 32 inch display...

Comment: The idea behind the 20x20 is that it auto-resize to max_dimension on most monitors, or at least that's the behaviour I have observed with tkAgg. 
Using macOSX seems to solve the "slowness", but then I can not change the dimensions anymore and the auto-resize does not work.
Trying pyqt5 results in `ValueError: 'pyqt5' is not a valid value for backend; supported values are ['GTK3Agg', 'GTK3Cairo', 'MacOSX', 'nbAgg', 'Qt4Agg', 'Qt4Cairo', 'Qt5Agg', 'Qt5Cairo', 'TkAgg', 'TkCairo', 'WebAgg', 'WX', 'WXAgg', 'WXCairo', 'agg', 'cairo', 'pdf', 'pgf', 'ps', 'svg', 'template']`

Comment: If you really want to do this you might try to maximize the window?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439588/how-to-maximize-a-plt-show-window-using-python

Comment: @JodyKlymak I saw that page but there is no proposed solution for macOSX backend, and it doesn't seem like I am able to use qt or wx backends... (maybe I am doing something wrong when trying to implement them?)

edit: the use of macOSX isn't feasible: it stops all the interactions with the figure, so I can't zoom or save it, making the plot almost useless.

Comment: Try qt5agg.  Sorry for being confusing

Comment: @JodyKlymak oh ok, thanks! qt5agg works on both screens. It skips some frames, but that's not the end of the world and I can definitely live with it. (but if you have a fast solution for this problem I'd love to implement it)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give a direct answer without running your code but the symptoms you are describing (works on an external monitor but not the internal one) sounds like you may be running into a GPU bug.  External monitors may use a different GPU (usually the second GPU vs the built-in GPU).  But the fact this simple script shows that slowdown implies there is a bug (your code, the driver, somewhere) or the function calls are causing a problem.

The figures seem tiny compared to what your are plotting: a figure size of 10x10 with a marker size of 15?  I would start commenting out lines one by one using the built-in monitor until it gets fast again. There may also be a more efficient way to clear the axes and replot -- I've found Python / plt is very slow when I try to clear a figure and redraw.  You may also want to try creating the subplot outside of your loop since some implementations/OSs have a lot of overhead for creating subplots.

Comment: If it's a GPU problem, do you have any idea of how to force the usage of a specific GPU? or any other suggestion?
About the rest, I think sizes aren't really related, the figure is huge (20x20 is larger than the screen), the subplot fits and the marker is there as a decoration. 

Do you think I can upload a 'energy_data_dynamics' file for others to test the code?