# Matplotlib, Python, How to create new figure window on a specific screen location?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I wonder if I can specific an argument to tell matplotlib to create a new figure at a specific location on the screen given a coordinate?

```
resultWindow = figure(2, figsize=(10, 10))
```

I checked the documentation and there seems to have no such argument.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a completely backend-agnostic way of doing this. The answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802366/matplotlib-window-layout-questions) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449585/how-do-you-set-the-absolute-position-of-figure-windows-with-matplotlib) might be some help, for example if you use the `wx` or `TkAgg` backends

Comment: Also, to complete @tom's comment, on Qt4Agg backend you can use `thismanager.window.move(x, y)` (following the example from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7450808/5216568)).